# django views, getting request and using it as a parameter

Tags: python, django

I'm very confused about this right now, 
so I know when there's a simple code like the below

```
def text_detail(request ,course_pk, step_pk):
    step = get_object_or_404(Text, course_id = course_pk, pk=step_pk)
```

course_pk and step_pk from the url, and those requests are set equal to course_id and pk here. but what I don't understand is what is course_id and pk here? I mean, course_id is from Course model which is foreignkey to step. so it's self.Course.id so it's course_id. But then, how about the next one pk? shouldn't it be step_id = step_pk? when it's just pk how does django know which pk it is? 
Sorry if the question is very confusing, I'm very confused right now.

Edit

```
class Step(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        ordering = ['order',]
    def __str__(self):
        self.title
class Text(Step):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the `get_or_404()` method doing a similar/exact job as below,

```
try:
    return Text.object.get(pk=step_pk,course_id = course_pk)
except Text.DoesNotExist:
    raise Http404
```

You can read the [source code of the same here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/shortcuts.py#L74)

What is `course_id` and `pk` ?
Both are attributes of your `Text` model, as the name indicates `pk` is your Primary Key of `Text` model and `course_id` is the `id`/`pk` of `course` field which is a FK.

EDIT
`Text` is inherited from `Step` model so, it will show properties of usual python class.Hence, the `Text` model be like this internally (not-exact)

```
class Text(models.Model):
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, default="")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField()
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    course = models.ForeignKey(Course)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['order', ]
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Example

```
text = Text.objects.get(id=1) # text instance with id=1
text.course_id # will hold the id of "course" instance which is related to the particular "text" instance
```

URL assignment and all those stuffs are entirely depends on your choice and logic. So If you need to get a `Text` instance in your view, do as below,

```
text = get_object_or_404(Text, pk = pk_of_TEXT_instance)
```

Comment: so when it's foreignkey I need to do course_id instead of just doing id? in my case Text model is like class Text(Step), so shouldn't it be step_pk instead of just pk?

Comment: You should add you relevant codes and requirements in question. please do it

Comment: what I'm very confused about is this, so when we get step_pk from url request we make it equal to pk which is a primary key of Text and we use the data from Text model? but then what's the difference between just pk and text_pk?

Comment: you said, `we make it equal to pk` , This is not `equal to`, its an `assignment` operation

Comment: yes that's what I meant but can you help me with my confusion still?

Comment: Ok. Can you add you `model.py` in question ? If so I could help you with examples

Comment: just ediited the question